# how to compare two columns and get the mean value of the the 3rd column for all matching items in the two in python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have the following table named **Rides** :

| start_id | end_id | eta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 5 |
| B | C | 4 |
| A | C | 6 |
| A | B | 5 |
| B | A | 3 |
| C | A | 3 |
| B | C | 6 |
| C | A | 5 |
| A | B | 8 |

From the **Rides** Table ,
I want to Create a new table which should look like something like below :

| start_id | end_id | mean _eta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 6 ((5+5+8)/3) |
| B | C | 5 ((4+6)/2)) |
| A | C | 6 |
| B | A | 3 |
| C | A | 4 ((3+5)/2)) |

so mean_eta of 1st row is returning 8 as there are three matching rides between start_ID = **"A"**  and end_ID = **"B"** with eta **5,5,8** , so the **mean_eta =  (5+5+8)/3 = 6**
How should I do it  ? Please help .

Comment: I'd think `(5 + 5 + 8) / 3 == 6`?

Comment: `df.groupby(['start_id', 'end_id']).mean()`.  Please check out the Pandas Docs for a quick intro: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

groupby and get the aggregate mean. Code below;

```
df.groupby(['start_id','end_id'])['eta'].agg('mean').to_frame('eta-mean')
```